# Diferencia entre new Array() en ES5 y Array.of() en ES6 en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Cuando usamos el **Constructor** `new Array()` en `ES5` para construir un nuevo arreglo hacemos lo siguiente:

**EJEMPLO 1**

```
let elementos = new Array(2);
console.log(elementos[0]);
console.log(elementos[1]);
//ambos console darán undefined
```

Sin embargo ¿cual es el problema?

En el ejemplo anterior, el valor numérico que le fue pasado se asume con la longitud del arreglo, pero cada posición del mismo arreglo carece de elementos

**EJEMPLO 2**

```
let elementos = new Array("alfa");
console.log(elementos[0]); //imprime alfa
console.log(elementos[1]); //imprime undefined
```

En el ejemplo anterior el único elemento pasado no es numérico si no una cadena de texto, misma que se asume en la posición cero del arreglo y la siguiente poisición será undefined

**EJEMPLO 3**

```
let elementos = new Array("alfa", "BETO");
console.log(elementos[0]); //imprime alfa
console.log(elementos[1]);  //imprime BETO
```

En el ejemplo anterior le hemos pasado dos valores, no numéricos; mismos que son colocados en cada posición del arreglo

*¿Cómo soluciona esto `Array.of()`?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La similitud es que los dos crean una instancia de un `Array` y la diferencia significativa entre `Array()` y [Array.of()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/of) es solo el comportamiento de su constructor.

Cuando pasamos **un solo** valor numérico como parámetro a `Array` este parámetro preestablece la longitud *(length)* del `Array` pero con [Array.of()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/of) lo que espera son elementos o valores con los cuales construirá el `array`, dependiendo de la cantidad, se establecerá la longitud. Sí pasa un solo valor *numérico o no* este se añadirá a la primer posición.

**Ejm**

```js
let array = new Array(9);
console.log(array);
console.log("Length Array " + array.length);
let arrayOf = Array.of(9);
console.log(arrayOf);
console.log("Length Array.of " +arrayOf.length);
let arrayOf2 = Array.of("Nueve");
console.log(arrayOf2);
console.log("Length Array.of " +arrayOf2.length);
```

Eso solo es cuando se pasa **un solo parámetro**, si se envía más de un parámetro al constructor de `Array` *(no importa el "tipo")* , [se tomará en cuenta el segundo constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array#Se_crea_con) donde espera también todos los elementos de un array.

Se pueden pasar elemento por elemento, o pasar el array directamente utilizando El [Operador de Propagación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator), o `spread operator`

**Ejm**

```js
let elementos = [1,"a",4,6 , true];
let array = new Array(...elementos);
console.log(" Length Array " + array.length);
console.log(array);
let array2 = new Array(1,"a",false);
console.log(" Length Array " + array2.length);
console.log(array2);
let arrayOf = Array.of(...elementos);
console.log(" Length Array.of " + arrayOf.length);
console.log(arrayOf);
```

Answer (score 3):

Con el uso de `Array.of()` en `ES6` podemos hacer lo siguiente

**EJEMPLO 1**

```
let elementos = Array.of(12, 45);
console.log(elementos[0]);        //imprime 12     
console.log(elementos[1]);        //imprime 45
```

En el ejemplo anterior le estamos pasando dos valores que sin importar si son numéricos o no serán asignados como valor a cada posición del arreglo

**EJEMPLO 2**

```
let elementos = Array.of(12);
console.log(elementos[0]);    //imprime 12         
console.log(elementos[1]);    //imprime undefined
```

En el ejemplo anterior al contrario de `new Array()` el único valor numérico que le es pasado no se asume como la longitud del arreglo si no como el valor de la primer posición de array

**EJEMPLO 3**

```
let elementos = Array.of("67.4", false)
console.log(elementos[0])  //imprime "67.4"
console.log(elementos[1])  //imprime false
```

En el ejemplo anterior, podemos observar que el primer elemento es una cadena de texto y es asignado a la posición 0 y el segundo elemento es un valor booleano asignado a la posicón 1